# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.Net Core application I am getting this exception

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor'
>   has been registered

At runtime in my Checkout class specifically in my GetCart method.

```
        public static Checkout GetCart(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ISession session = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;

            var context = serviceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
            string checkoutId = session.GetString("CheckoutId") ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            session.SetString("CheckoutId", checkoutId);

            return new Checkout(context) { CheckoutId = checkoutId };
        }
```

I have added the `HttpContextAccessor` service in the startup.cs file

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped(sp => Checkout.GetCart(sp));
services.AddSession();
```

I even tried Adding using the `AddHttpContextAccessor();` method which is supposed to correctly add the service as a singleton but still get the same exception.

Adding as scope gave the runtime exception

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' from root provider.'

Anyone with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Any particular reason for using serviceProvider.GetRequiredService and not inject it through constructor?

Comment: I think this is to get a session that will be used in this method.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you inject it through the constructor and use `AddHttpContextAccessor();`?

Comment: @DaggeJ I dont know how to do that, I am already injecting my appdbcontext in constructor  ```        public Checkout(AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }
```

Comment: You would do that in a similar way. It just struck me that your problem is probably due to you trying to get a registered service by class name instead of its interface. Try using `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()` (not the I before Http...)

Comment: I just noticed that right now, I feel so stupid for the hours wasted trying to fix this issue. Thank you for the  insight

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```cs
ISession session = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;
```

to

```cs
ISession session = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use the interface, not the concrete implementation.

```cs
IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor = serviceProvider
    .GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?
```

Then use the built in extension to register the accessor.

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```